# Meteor click event, double click; Using only JS

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, click

I made click event when I press button div's style "display: none;" changes to "display: inline-flex". Now, everything is working fine, except when I click again on button he do not turn div back to "display: none;". Second problem is that with this button and click event he is showing only first comment. Here's the code:

**Template for showing comments of some post with div that is changing style**

```
<template name="PrikazKomentara">    
 <div id="{{IdRoditelja}}" style="display: none;">
    <div class="prikaze"><p>Коментар:</p>{{коментар}}</div>
    <div class="prikaze"><p>Коментарисао:</p>{{коментарисао}}</div>
 </div>
</template>
```

**Button that changes DIV's style**

```
<template name="PrikažiMe">
 <button class="PrikažiKomentar">Прикажи коментаре</button>
</template>
```

**Finely, template event**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.PrikažiMe.events({
    'click .PrikažiKomentar': function(){
        var prikaz = document.getElementById(this._id); 
        if (prikaz.style.display = "none") 
            { prikaz.style.display = "inline-flex" } 
        else {prikaz.style.display = "none"};
    }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=`means setting the display to `none`, not judge the display if it equals to `none`,

use `===` or `==`

Comment: So, something like:
' if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.PrikažiMe.events({
    'click .PrikažiKomentar': function(){
        var prikaz = document.getElementById(this._id); 
        if (prikaz.style.display === "none") 
            { prikaz.style.display = "inline-flex" } 
        else {prikaz.style.display = "none"};
    }
    });    
} '